# Join Multiple rows in one column for Unique ID

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery and I have data arranged in the following fashion. I want to join the columns and rows for Type, Make, Model for each Unique Order_ID.

| ORDER_ID | NR_ORDERS | TYPE | MAKE | MODEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZX | 3 | K | M | B |
| ZX | 2 | V | J | P |
| ZX | 1 | D | G | Y |
| AB | 2 | C | T | B |
| AB | 1 | G | H | B |

The output should look like this:

The columns for Type, Make, Model are merged in one row for each Order_ID.

| ORDER_ID | NR_ORDERS | JOINED_COLUMNS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ZX | 3 | K M B, V J P, D G Y |
| AB | 2 | C T B, G H B |

Thank you!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Any NULL values possible?

Comment: I'm connecting to BigQuery and there are no NULL values allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work in BigQuery:

```
SELECT order_id, COUNT(nr_orders) AS nr_orders, 
STRING_AGG(CONCAT(type, ' ', make, ' ', model), ', ')
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY order_id;
```

By way of explanation:

You need to do two things, first join (concatenate) the three columns type, make and model, and then aggregate on the resultant concatenation.  Therefore we use `CONCAT` first (which takes a succession of strings and joins them together), and then around that we use `STRING_AGG`.  Note that `CONCAT` returns `NULL` if any values are null.

I wasn't sure from your desired output, if the nr_orders should be the `COUNT` of the orders with the same id, or the `MAX` value.  But it is easy to change!